# How do I make the eyes follow the object?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im not entirely sure what's wrong with my code. The eyes (iris) seem to be locked on the bottom right corner of the eyes and are rotating around on that fixed position. I've looked at tutorials online and tried variety of codes, but none seem to work. The end goal that I would like to achieve is to have the eyes follow the given block.

Thank you in advance!

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', eyeball);
function eyeball() {
  const eye = document.querySelectorAll('.eye');
  eye.forEach(function(eye){
    let x = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().left) + (eye.clientWidth / 2);
    let y = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().top) + (eye.clientHeight / 2);

    let radian = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY - y);
    let rotation = (radian * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 270;
    eye.style.transform = "rotate("+rotation+"deg)";
  });
}
```

```css
.eye-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: pink;
}

.eyeball{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pupil{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  border: 10px solid purple;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="eye-container">
  <div class="eyelids eyelid-left"></div>
  <div class="eyelids eyelid-right"></div>
  <div class=" eyeball left-eye">
    <div class=" eye pupil left-pupil"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="eyeball right-eye">
    <div class="eye pupil right-pupil"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't think it has anything to do with the issue but you have a superfluous closing `</div>` after the "left eye" block. I also edited your post so it can be run as a snippet

Comment: Hi Victor, Thank you for the post correction as well as the correction on the extra `</div>` (fixed that in the code)! I'll also keep in mind in the future to set snippets for question posts. But unfortunately, fixing the div didn't help with the eye movement in my code :(

Comment: Hello! Currently you're only rotation the eyes in place. That does not seems like what you actually want to do. You'll need to adjust the eyes position aswell to have them move within the eyeballs.

Comment: Hello R.A.E, In one of my previous attempts to resolving the issue, I tried setting the function to the eyeball, but that only rotated the whole eyes in a misshapen, egg liked shape :/ what I would like is to have the whole pupil move freely/follow the block within the eyeball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably something more like this. This will translate the pupils into place, giving it that "following look".

```
function eyeball(target_x, target_y) {
  const eye = document.querySelectorAll('.eye');
  eye.forEach(function(eye){
    let x = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().left) + (eye.clientWidth / 2);
    let y = (eye.getBoundingClientRect().top) + (eye.clientHeight / 2);
    let radian = Math.atan2(target_x - x, target_y - y);
    let transform_x = Math.round(Math.sin(radian) * 100);
    let transform_y = Math.round(Math.cos(radian) * 100);
    eye.style.transform = "translate(" + transform_x + "%, " + transform_y + "%)";
  });
}
```

You will also need to change the initial style of the pupils to get a correct offset for the position change.

```
.pupil{
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  border: 10px solid purple;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```